# JQuery validation plugin - set custom dynamic message from server

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to catch and show custom error message from the server side on the html page?

```
function getAlertMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "getAlert.do",
        success : function(data) {
            data.alertmsg //How to set this msg to validatename property  in messages Attribute
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("No Court No details found");
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#register-form").validate({
       rules : {
        username : {
          required : true,
          validname : true,
          minlength : 4
         }
        },
       messages : {
        username : {
         required : "Please Enter UserName",
         validname : getAlertMessage(), //it does not worked here
         minlength : "UserName is Too Short"}},
         errorPlacement : function(error,element) {
           $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html(
error.html());
},
         highlight : function(element) {
         $(element).closest('.form-group')
         .removeClass('has-success')
         .addClass('has-error');
          },
         unhighlight : function(element,
         errorClass, validClass) {
         $(element).closest('.form-group')
         .removeClass('has-error')
         .addClass('has-success');
         $(element).closest('.form-group')
        .find('.help-block').html('');},
          submitHandler : function(form) {
           form.submit();}});});
```

Comment: You either call `validate` inside the success handler, or you change that setting in the success handler by accessing `$("#register-form").validate().settings`

Comment: Can you show me in Jsfiddle please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on this kind of issue and finally got it working. There is nothing similar online and this feels like a good place to put it as it directly relates to the question asked.

So what I needed was a server side function to do a check and decide what error message to return based on checking a database (a bit like a cms). This message needed to be displayed to the user and validate the field accordingly.

It might not be the best/cleanest way but it works and I don't think it's that bad! Basically, there needs to be a hidden field on the page to store the error message. So here's how I got it to work:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("customValidation", [], function (options) {
    options.rules["remote"] = {
        url: "/api/CustomValidation",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            fieldValue: function () { return options.element.value; }
        },
        beforeSend : function () {
            // Show loading gif
            $('#loader').show();
        },
        dataFilter: function (data) {
            // if the API returns a JSON string then this is needed
            var result = JSON.parse(data);

            if (result != undefined && result != null) {
                if (result.ErrorMessage != null) {
                    // update a hidden field on the page with the message.
                    $('#HdnValidationMessage').val(result.ErrorMessage);

                    // Field is not valid so return false
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    // no error message returned so field must be valid
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                // Something has gone wrong! I won't let this stop the user.
                return true;
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            // hide loading gif
            $('#loader').hide();
        }
    };

    // Default error message set to fetch the error fromt he hidden field.
    options.messages["remote"] = function() { return $('#HdnValidationMessage').val(); }
});
```

Hope it helps someone who was stuck for a while on this like I was!

**UPDATE:**

Got this working without a hidden field. Not sure why I couldn't before but now it's much more straight forward.

So now the controller action server-side returns true if valid and an error message if incorrect. the below will display the error message:

```
 jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("customValidation", [], function (options) {
    options.rules["remote"] = {
        url: "/api/CustomValidation",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            fieldValue: function () { return options.element.value; }
        },
        beforeSend : function () {
            // Show loading gif
            $('#loader').show();
            $(options.element).prop("readonly", "readonly");
        },
        complete: function () {
            // hide loading gif
            $('#loader').hide();
            $(options.element).removeProp("readonly");
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why would you need to do this** when a `remote` method already exists?

Since this seems like nothing more than a server call to validate the `username` field, use the method designed for this purpose.  From the server, send back `true`, `false`, or a JSON encoded string that represents a dynamic custom validation message.

The value of the field being validated by `remote` is already sent by default, so you'd only need to define the `url` and `type` parameters.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                remote: {
                    url: 'getAlert.do',
                    type: 'POST'
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please Enter UserName",
                minlength: "UserName is Too Short"
                // DO NOT NEED 'remote' message since it's already coming from server
            }
        }, .....
```

That's all you'd need to define within `rules` and `messages`.  The value of `username` is sent to your `getAlert.do` function on the server.

Then from your server, `getAlert.do` would need to send back a `true` if you want validation to pass, and a JSON encoded string representing the error message when you want validation to fail.

See:  [jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Comment: getAlert.do will return an array of json objects.How do i check the condition and its respective message?